# Redirect to website/username

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my root directory I have a users file that contains `<a href="/dashboard?name={$row['sub_user']}">` and I want it to go to username.website/sub_user. This rewrite works fine but all .php requests ar going to username.website/dashboard instead of username.website/sub_user. Can you please tell me why?

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dashboard?`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ dashboard?name=$1 [L]`

I also have some rules to get rid of the php extension:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^no-redirect-loop(&|$)`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$  $1  [NS,R=301,L]`

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^no-redirect-loop(&|$)`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php?no-redirect-loop  [NS,QSA]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is incorrect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dashboard?
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ dashboard?name=$1 [L]
```

Since it is sending `foo.php` file to `/dashboard?name=foo`

Change your rule to this to make it work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ dashboard?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is perfect but the result comes with .php and I can't get the sub_user. Please see the edit.

Comment: Got it, I had to .php here ^([^/]+).php/?$. Thank you!